# dilema de regex en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

tengo una variable `cuenta` que tiene el valor `"3!+4!"` andentro, quiero buscar todos los `!` (con sus respectivos numeros) que existan para cambiarlos por la funcion factorial de math(math.factorial()), iba a usar `re.sub(r"\d+\!")` para buscarlo pero no se como decir que lo que encuentre, llamemoslo x, me realize la operacion `factorial(eval(x[0:len(x-1)]))` de forma que retorne `cuenta = 6+24`.

estaba intentando utilizar algo parecido a:

```
re.sub(x=r"\d+\!", factorial(eval(x[0:len(x)-1])), cuenta)
```

donde en x guardo lo encontrado y lo reemplazo por el factorial solo del numero, pero no me deja.

alguna idea de que pueda hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
import re
from math import factorial

cadena = "3!+4!+(5!/3!)"
regex = r"(\d+)!"
template = re.sub(regex, "{}", cadena)
numeros = re.findall(regex, cadena)
resultado = template.format(*(factorial(int(n)) for n in numeros))
print(resultado)
```

```
6+24+(120/6)
```

### Explicación

- La expresión regular `(\d+)!` encajará con cualquier secuencia de dígitos que lleve una admiración al final y *además*, gracias a los paréntesis, **capturará** cuál ha sido la secuencia de dígitos.
- Usando `re.sub()` sustituyo todos los match de la expresión regular por parejas de llaves. Observa que esto reemplaza el match completo, que incluye el signo de admiración, y no sólo el grupo capturado que no lo incluiría. En el ejemplo daría como resultado `'{}+{}+({}/{})'`, lo cual deja preparada una plantilla para después usar con `.format()`, y poder así reemplazar cada pareja de llaves por el correspondiente factorial.
- Usando `re.findall()` obtengo una lista con todos los grupos capturados. En el ejemplo la lista resultante sería `['3', '4', '5', '3']`, que se guarda en la variable `numeros`. Contiene los números cuyo factorial hay que calcular.
- Mediante la expresión generadora `factorial(int(n)) for n in numeros` genero los correspondientes factoriales de los números en cuestión. En nuestro caso esa expresión generará las cantidades `6, 24, 120, 6`.
- Mediante el operador `*` delante de la expresión generadora, convierto ese iterable en una serie de parámetros separados, que le paso a `format()`.
- Ese `.format()` lo aplico al template antes preparado que tenía parejas de llaves en sitios estratégicos, y así obtengo la cadena final `'6+24+(120/6)'`

Cabe señalar que puede ponerse todo en una sola línea, pero francamente creo que se hace demasiado críptico (y ya lo era sin necesidad de esto). Como curiosidad, la línea sería:

```
re.sub(regex, "{}", cadena).format(*(factorial(int(n)) for n in re.findall(regex, cadena)))
```

## Ampliación

A petición del usuario amplío un poco la misión del `*`.

Este es un operador que tiene python que permite "desempaquetar" una lista o una tupla (o en este ejemplo concreto una expresión generadora) y convertirlo en una serie de argumentos separados por comas. La mejor forma de explicarlo será con un ejemplo.

Cuando tienes una función que recibe, por ejemplo, tres parámetros, la forma normal de llamarla sería: `funcion(1, 2, 3)`. En este caso se dice de los parámetros que son *posicionales*, pues son asignados a los declarados en la función según la posición que ocupan. Es decir, que si la función está declarada con un `def funcion(a,b,c)`, la invocación anterior asignará 1 al parámetro `a`, 2 al `b` y 3 al `c` (Python también tiene otra forma de invocar la función en la que no se asignan por posición, sino por nombre).

Pues bien, ahora imagina que tienes una lista `l = [1,2,3]` y que quieres llamar a la función pasando los elementos de esa lista como parámetros. Naturalmente `funcion(l)` no servirá, pues eso asignaría la lista completa al parámetro `a` y dejaría `b` y `c` sin valor.

La solución, si no conoces el operador `*`, sería hacer `funcion(l[0], l[1], l[2])`, pero el operador `*` permite algo más conciso y elegante: `funcion(*l)`. El resultado es que la lista `l` se "desempaqueta" y cada uno de sus valores se convierte en un parámetro separado.

Esto funciona también en funciones que admiten un número variable de parámetros, como `str.format()`. La lista en este caso puede tener cualquier número de elementos. También funciona si `l`, en lugar de una lista, es una tupla o una expresión generadora.

En el código de mi respuesta, la variable `template` tiene `{}` en cuatro posicionies, por lo que a `format` habría que pasarle cuatro parámetros. La lista `numeros` tiene cuatro elementos, por lo que la expresión generadora dará como resultado cuatro factoriales, y el `*` lo convertirá en los cuatro parámetros que `.format()` necesita para rellenar los cuatro `{}` en el `template`.

Date cuenta de que esto es tremendamente flexible y potente, pues todo depende de cuál hubiera sido la `cadena` inicial, y se "adapta" automáticamente a cualquier número de factoriales que esta cadena pudiera contener, ya que si sólo hubiera tres expresiones factoriales en ella, `template` tendría sólo tres `{}` y `numeros` sólo tres elementos. Así que todo encaja de nuevo. No se podría haber hecho esto sin el operador `*`.

Comment: hola, primero que todo muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Segundo, me gustaria saber como funciona el * antes de la funcion generadora, porque no enteiendo muy bien su proposito.

Comment: @Mr.Barbo He ampliado la respuesta. Espero aclare tus dudas

Comment: Ya comprendí, muchas gracias.